# Is the projections to a factor in a submodule of a direct sum over a unital ring, a submodule of the ring?

Tags: ring-theory, direct-sum

Let $R$ be a ring with unity (not neccessarily commutative), and say we have a finite direct sum $$\bigoplus_{i = 1}^{n}R$$ and a submodule $$K \subseteq \bigoplus_{i = 1}^{n} R.$$ If we now view $R$ with the natural $R$-module structure, we know that the direct sum can also be given an $R$-module structure.

Is it the case the projection $$\pi_i:K \to K_j$$ is a *submodule* of $R$, and hence an ideal of $R$ (with $R$ having the $R$-module structure)?

We have that $$0 \in K_j \implies K_j \neq \emptyset$$ and furthermore, if $$x,y \in K_j, r \in R \implies x+ry \in K_j$$ where we identify an element $k_j$ as being in $K_j$ if there exist an element $k \in K$ such that it's j:th component is $k_j$.

I am not entirely sure about this, it feels like something is wrong with my definition, but I can´t quite put my finger on it.

Note that I only handle the finite case here, but I don´t think the infinite case necessarily changes things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is fine. The following more general facts are true:

1. If $f : M \to N$ is an $R$-module homomorphism, then the image $f(K)$ of a submodule $K \subseteq M$ is a submodule of $N$.
2. If $\bigoplus_{i \in I} M_i$ is a direct sum (possibly infinite) of $R$-modules, then for each $j$ the projection $\pi_j : \bigoplus_i M_i \to M_j$ to $M_j$ is an $R$-module homomorphism. (The same is true for products $\prod_{i \in I} M_i$, again possibly infinite.)
3. A left resp. right ideal of $R$ is a left resp. right submodule of $R$.

But! Note that $K$ is not the direct sum of the $K_j$.

Comment: Hm, I see, so suppose for example that we have a free $R$-module $F$, so that $$F \cong \bigoplus_{i \in I} R.$$ Suppose furthermore that $K \subseteq F$ is a submodule. Can I then claim that $K_j$ in $$\pi_j:K \twoheadrightarrow K_j$$ is such that $$K_j \cong I$$ for some ideal $I$ in $R$?

Comment: @Ben123: if $R$ is not necessarily commutative then the term "ideal" is ambiguous, and you also need to disambiguate between left and right modules. If $K$ is a left resp. right submodule then the $K_j$ are left resp. right ideals.

Comment: Oh, yes, correct. Thank you. 

Best.

Comment: I should probably then be able to use this, on the second part of: 

"If $$A \otimes_{R} I \to A \otimes_{R} R$$ is injective for every finitely generated ideal $I$, prove that
$$A \otimes_{R} I \to A \otimes_{R} R$$ is injective for every ideal $I$ . Show that if $K$ is any submodule of a finitely generated free module $F$ then $$A \otimes_{R} K \to A \otimes_{R} F$$ is injective. Show that the same is true for any free module $F$."


(From D & F, chapter 10.5 exercise 25.(b))

Comment: Well, maybe not, I have to think, since if what you said is correct, I can´t really identify $K$ as a direct sum $K_j$:s. But I want to convert the second part onto something I can use the first part on.

The only answers to this problem I´ve seen on this site, uses the Tor-functor, I believe. But I have not covered that in my course, and I don´t think you should have to use that concept.

Comment: I don't think the $K_j$'s will help you solve this exercise. What is $A$ here?

Comment: $A$ is an $R$-module. The exercise is basically to show that $A$ is a *flat* $R$-module *if and only if* for every finitely generated ideal $I$ of $R$, we have that the map $$A \otimes_{R} I \to A \otimes_{R} R \cong A$$ induced by the inclusion $I \subseteq R$ is injective. 

I believe an equivalent formulation is $$A \otimes_{R} I \cong AI.$$

Comment: I should add that when D & F calls something $R$-module, it is understood that they mean *left* $R$-module, unless something else is stated (see chapter 10.1, first page). Although, in this case, it might be that you should actually think of $A$ as having a right-module structure as well, since this is the standard-tensor product one wants, i.e. we want $$a \otimes ri = ar \otimes i \in A \otimes_{R} I$$ to hold.

Comment: You need $I$ to be a left ideal and $A$ to be a right module for these tensor products to make sense, unless the assumption here is that $R$ is commutative. In any case if you are still having trouble with this exercise you should ask about it in a separate question.

Comment: Yeah, this question has already been asked (and shut down), by others, so I don´t think there is any point in asking it. But I believe I have a general idea of how to go about solving it (without the use of Tor-functors).

Comment: Basically, since $\{e_i\}$ is a basis for $F$, it is a basis for $K$, and then you can rewrite everything in $A \otimes_{R} K$ on the form $$\sum_{i = 1}^{n} a_i \otimes e_i \quad(\text{also assuming right R-module structure on A}.)$$ Since $$A \otimes_{R} F \cong A^n$$ there is a natural map from $$A \otimes_{R} I \to A^n$$ and  it will be clear that if $$(a_1,\ldots,a_n) = (a'_1,\ldots,a'_n) \implies \sum_{i} a_i \otimes e_i = \sum_{i} a'_i \otimes e_i.$$

I´d be interested if you agree or not (in the general idea). I don´t claim this is a complete proof. :)